# How to call a cmake method from shell script?

Tags: shell, cmake, cmake-language, cmakelists-options

I have a parameterised function in `mytestprogram.cmake` written like below:

```
function(get_output_from_input output input) 
    set(${output} "test" PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

**Question:**
How do I call the cmake method `get_output_from_input` from a shell script?

I learnt that there is `-P <source.cmake>` flag, that puts CMake into script processing mode and we can execute arbitrary CMake code with it using something like below.

```
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_PROGRAM} -P yourscript.cmake)
```

So, in this case I believe the way to call `get_output_from_input` from a shell script would be something like below?

```
input="some_input"
output=""
execute_process(get_output_from_input(output, input) ${CMAKE_PROGRAM} -P mytestprogram.cmake)
echo $output
```

But above trick does not work. Is the way I am running `execute_process` correct?

Trying to figure out whats wrong, it seems `echo $CMAKE_PROGRAM` returns empty? Could that be the reason? What am I missing here to call `get_output_from_input`?

**Environment:**
cmake version 3.18.2
macOS Catalina

Comment: I corrected the syntax of `get_output_from_input`.

Comment: Obviously you cannot run a script or part of it without proper **interpreter**. You cannot run a shell script without a shell (`sh`, `bash`, etc.), you cannot run a CMake script without `cmake`. Also, all definitions (functions, variables) in the script are only visible to its interpreter: you cannot read a variable defined in CMake script outside of CMake, you cannot run a function defined in CMake script outside of CMake. The only exception is **environment** variables, because they are simply not a script variables: the notion of environment variables is shared across scripting languages.

Comment: Thats a very good explanation to my question. Thanks for explaining why @Tsyvarev

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cmake -P` executes an entire script, not a single function defined in a CMake file, so need to add an additional script file that you can then execute via `cmake -P`. Arguments to a script executed via `cmake -P` need to be passed as CMake variables, e.g. `cmake -DINPUT=some_input -P myscript.cmake` .

Since you need the output of the CMake script in an bash variable, the CMake script "mytestscript.cmake" would look something like this:

```
# make `get_output_from_input` available in current script
# assuming the script file is located next to `mytestprogram.cmake`
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mytestprogram.cmake)

get_output_from_input(RESULT "${INPUT}")

message("${RESULT}")
```

and the shell script contains

```
#!/bin/bash
input="some_input"

# assumes `mytestscript.cmake` is located in the current working directory
output=$(cmake -DINPUT="${input}" -P mytestscript.cmake 2>&1)

# Below statement should print the value of output.
echo $output
```

Regarding `execute_process`: That is meant to be used if you need to execute another process from within a CMake script, not to execute a CMake script from a shell process. Depending on what you plan to do with the output of the CMake script you could possibly use `execute_process` instead of additional bash.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking a look. I don't need the output of `get_output_from_input` in an environment variable. I just need it in a variable in the shell script.

Comment: `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mytestprogram.cmake)` is to be called from shell script?

Comment: Do you mind simplifying your answer a bit? I just need the output of that cmake method in a variable in my `.sh` shell script and `echo` it out. Thats it.

Comment: Please note that I did not mean to call `get_output_from_input` from `CMakeLists.txt`. I meant, how to call it from a shell script.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer `include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/mytestprogram.cmake` needs to be called from the CMake script you intend to execute with `cmake -P`. I've given names to the script files now to hopefully make it easier to follow.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer *I meant, how to call it from a shell script* You can't directly call CMake functions from bash, you need a CMake script that calls the function. As shown in the answer that CMake script is just a small additional wrapper that doesn't need to be used in a `CMakeLists.txt` project configuration script.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining. I am trying to make your example code work.

Comment: Have you tried your code? Running the cmake script from the shell complains `CMake Error: Error processing file: mytestscript.cmake`. I even tried hard coding the path of `mytestprogram.cmake`.

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer Yes I've tested it (which is why I just noticed that CMake doesn't output on stdout for some reason, so you need to add the redirect `2>1` in the assignment of the output to the `output` variable in the bash script). Is your working directory correct? You currently need to be in the same directory as the shell and cmake scripts in order to run this.

Comment: I have place all the 3 files in the same directory. Now the error is gone but `output` variable in shell script is empty? Can you please add `echo $output` to print out the value of `output` to the console?

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer Sorry I forgot the ampersand in the shell redirect, it should work now

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. It works :D This was a fantastic learning for me. Accepting your answer :D

Comment: @TheWaterProgrammer I just noticed that inputs with semicolons weren't handled correctly and have fixed `mytestscript.cmake` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

What I think you're asking for—setting a Bash variable directly from CMake's script mode—is impossible. The script mode (`-P`) just lets you run CMake code without a project / build directory. And [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) is a *CMake* command, not a shell command, so calling it from sh/bash is bound to fail.

The CMake function you wrote is wrong, too. All it does is write to a local variable which is never read and immediately gets destroyed. You probably wanted [`set(VAR "VALUE" PARENT_SCOPE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-normal-variable). The `return()` is pointless and should be removed.

If you [explained a bit more about what you were trying to do](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem), maybe this question would be answerable.

---

Here's a basic demonstration of CMake's script mode:

```
# ./script.cmake
# Input variable: file
# Output: md5sum of file

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

file(MD5 "${file}" hash)
message("${hash}")
```

Running this from the terminal (equiv. a shell script):

```
$ ls
my_file.txt  script.cmake
$ cat my_file.txt
Hello, world!
$ cmake -Dfile=my_file.txt -P script.cmake
746308829575e17c3331bbcb00c0898b
```

Comment: I corrected the syntax in my .cmake file. Thanks for pointing it out. You mean it is impossible to call a function in .cmake file from within a shell script?

Comment: Correct, you cannot directly call a CMake function from a shell script. You can do what I did in the example, however, and write a CMake script that loads your function, calls it, and prints the result.